# I can not secure copy files between my servers

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat, scp

I have two servers , 
SERVER1: the first is installed with Redhat 7.7 
SERVER2: the second server is installed with Redhat 6.10

The problem can be described in below 4 point:

1- I can ssh from SERVER1 to SERVER 2 and vice versa 
as below:

```
> SERVER1,root,root # ssh SERVER2
> 
> Last login: Sat May 16 02:06:48 2020 from x.x.x.x
> 
> Agent pid 103002
> 
> SERVER2,root,root #
```

To be noted that there is a new file is created under /tmp

```
> SERVER2,root,root # ll /tmp/ssh-tuqA103001
> 
> total 0
> 
> srw------- 1 root root 0 May 21 11:45 agent.103001
> 
> SERVER2,root,root #
```

also ssh command ommits output Agent pid 103002 as above
each time a new file is created with a new number

2- I can ssh from SERVER2 to SERVER1 as below:

```
    > SERVER2,root,root # ssh SERVER1 
    > Last login: Thu May 21 11:13:45 2020
    > from x.x.x.x 
    > SERVER1,root,root #
```

to be noted that ssh does not omit the agent pid nor create any files under /tmp

3- I can scp any file from SERVER2 to SERVER1 as below:

```
> SERVER2,root,root # scp -rp test.sh SERVER1:/tmp 
> test.sh              100%  470     0.5KB/s   00:00  
> SERVER2,root,root#
```

4- But I can't transfer any file from SERVER1 to SERVER2 as below:

```
> SERVER1,root,root # scp -rp foo SERVER2:/tmp 
> Agent pid 107142
> SERVER1,root,root #
```

I have captured the debug log for this scp failure as below:

```
SERVER1,root,root # scp -rpvvv foo SERVER2:/tmp
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host SERVER2, user (unspecified), command scp -v -r -p -t /tmp
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 49: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "SERVER2" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to SERVER2 [SERVER2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to SERVER2:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from SERVER2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=16 dh_need=16
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=16 dh_need=16
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1577/3072
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:Pcht7p5vfFNXT6fZIcf8m7qG3xdMViWiIVKGcaHV/xg
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 135.183.142.155
debug1: Host '135.183.142.155' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1542/3072
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55ebe8e53f10)
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa (0x55ebe8e54300)
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:y9b1WKq87QvObEImsrh2qzj4Xucf4Zcq2Zz9uCEWfiw
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:y9b1WKq87QvObEImsrh2qzj4Xucf4Zcq2Zz9uCEWfiw
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to SERVER2 ([SERVER2]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env GUESTFISH_INIT
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env QTDIR
debug3: Ignored env QTINC
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM_CHECKED
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env ENV
debug3: Ignored env GUESTFISH_PS1
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env GUESTFISH_OUTPUT
debug3: Ignored env PS1
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env QTLIB
debug3: Ignored env CVS_RSH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env GUESTFISH_RESTORE
debug3: Ignored env HISTFILE
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -r -p -t /tmp
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
Agent pid 107427
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
ionnoclab2,root,root # debug2: channel 0: write failed
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: send eow
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: output open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3312, received 2880 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 41262.8, received 35880.7
debug1: Exit status 0
SERVER1,root,root #**
```

What do you think the issue is? and how to solve it?

Comment: but root login is allowed I can login from one server to another as root as in above description

Comment: Do you have any other ideas that might solve the issue?

Comment: Any chance you can upgrade the ssh and scp clients on your antique RHEL 6 box? E.g. finding a custom RPM somewhere, installing it in a custom place, and running a few tests against the (more recent) ssh daemon on your RHEL 7 box